# Hive: Joining two tables with different keys

Tags: hadoop, hql, hive, hiveql

I have two tables like below. Basically i want to join both of them and expected the result like below.

First 3 rows of table 2 does not have any activity id just empty.

All fields are tab separated. Category "33" is having three description as per table 2.

We need to make use of "Activity ID" to get the result for "33" category as there are 3 values for that.

could anyone tell me how to achieve this output?

## TABLE: 1

Empid   Category    ActivityID

44126   33  TRAIN

44127   10  UFL

44128   12  TOI

44129   33  UNASSIGNED

44130   15  MICROSOFT

44131   33  BENEFITS

44132   43  BENEFITS

## TABLE 2:

Category    ActivityID  Categdesc

10      billable

12      billable

15      Non-billable

33  TRAIN   Training

33  UNASSIGNED  Bench

33  BENEFITS    Benefits

43      Benefits

## Expected Output:

44126  33  Training

44127  10  Billable

44128  12  Billable

44129  33  Bench

44130  15  Non-billable

44131  33  Benefits

44132  43  Benefits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's little difficult to do this Hive as there are many limitations. This is how I solved it but there could be a better way.

I named your tables as below.
Table1 = EmpActivity
Table2 = ActivityMas

The challenge comes due to the null fields in Table2. I created a view and Used UNION to combine result from two distinct queries.

```
Create view actView AS Select * from ActivityMas Where Activityid ='';

SELECT * From (
Select EmpActivity.EmpId, EmpActivity.Category, ActivityMas.categdesc
from EmpActivity JOIN ActivityMas 
ON  EmpActivity.Category =  ActivityMas.Category 
AND EmpActivity.ActivityId = ActivityMas.ActivityId
UNION ALL
Select EmpActivity.EmpId, EmpActivity.Category, ActView.categdesc from EmpActivity
JOIN ActView ON  EmpActivity.Category =  ActView.Category
)
```

You have to use top level SELECT clause as the UNION ALL is not directly supported from top level statements. This will run total 3 MR jobs. ANd below is the result I got.

```
44127   10      billable
44128   12      billable
44130   15      Non-billable
44132   43      Benefits
44131   33      Benefits
44126   33      Training
44129   33      Bench
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I could get the same answer how you are getting. It works with empty. Could you please let me know how to do it if first three Rows are some other string instead of "null/empty" for activityid?. I am also trying from my side.

Comment: What is the other possible value? Please provide me some sample values. In any case I think you can create the view accordingly and use.

Comment: Oops.. got the result with below view..


Create view actView1 AS Select * from queen Where actid <> 'TRAIN' and actid <> 'UNASSIGNED' and actid <> 'BENEFITS';

Thanks Rags and Brenden Brown for your help and time on this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand your question or your data, but would this work?

```
select table1.empid, table1.category, table2.categdesc
from table1 join table2
on table1.activityID = table2.activityID;
```

Comment: Thanks for your time on this. It works fine but could not get the expected result :(. Answer from Rags works and asked another similar help.